# scala, unable to prepend list

Tags: list, scala, concatenation

I am trying to append the concatenation of the head to the concatenation of the tail and the other list. However, I have an error: recursive method concat needs result type.

```
case z :: zs => z :: concat(zs, ys))
```

The error is at `::` when I do `z :: concat(zs, ys)`.

The full code:

```
def concat[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]) = xs match {
  case List() => ys
  case z :: zs => z :: concat(zs, ys)
}
var list_1 = List(1,2)
var list_2 = List(2,3)

var list_3 = concat(list_1, list_2)
```

Comment: Note: this is `list_1 ++ list_2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a sentence quoted from the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html):

> For recursive methods, the compiler is not able to infer a result type

Since you're defining your function recursively, you'll need to provide the result type of the function:

```
def concat[T](xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = xs match {
  case List() => ys
  case z :: zs => z :: concat(zs, ys)
}
```